# Elasticsearch status is active and running but cant able to connect using curl

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, elasticsearch-5

I get the following info using `status` command:

```bash
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status

elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-08-04 19:19:13 IST; 49s ago
    Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Process: 9974 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 9978 (java)
  CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
          └─9978 /usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOcc...
Aug 04 19:19:13 joy systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Aug 04 19:19:13 joy systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
```

But curl GET request to it fails:

```bash
curl -XGET "localhost:9200"
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/?pretty'

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if find, "No java runtime was found." in your log files.

```
Jul 30 18:28:13 dimik elasticsearch[10266]: [warning] /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: No java runtime was found
```

Here's my solution to the problem.

1. Check elasticsearch init file

   sudo nano /etc/init.d/elasticsearch

search for

```
. /usr/share/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh
find_java_runtime openjdk8 oracle8 openjdk7 oracle7 openjdk6 sun6 default
export JAVA_HOME
```

2. Check  java-wrappers.sh file

   sudo nano /usr/share/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh

Now you could see the warning comes from

```
#Displays a warning
java_warning() {
    echo "[warning] $0: $@" >&2;
}
```

3. Somehow, java directories are not listed in jvm-list.sh files

Now edit the jvm-list.sh file

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/java-wrappers/jvm-list.sh
```

Edit the line add your java directories files, in my case add /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle*

```
__jvm_oracle8="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-* /usr/lib/jvm/jre-8-oracle-* /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle*"
```

4. Now restart the service and check elasticsearch services

   sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
   sudo systemctl elasticsearch status
   curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200"